# Apache FOP - is there a way to embed font programmatically?

Tags: java, web, apache-fop

When creating a PDF using Apache FOP it is possible to embed a font with configuration file. The problem emerges when the app is a web application and it is necessary to embed a font that is inside WAR file (so treated as resource).

It is not acceptable to use particular container's folder structure to determine where exactly the war is located (when in configuration xml file we set  tag to `./`, it is set to the base folder of running container like `C:\Tomcat\bin`).

So the question is: Do anyone know the way to embed a font programatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After going through lots of FOP java code I managed to get it to work.

## Descriptive version

Main idea is to force FOP to use custom `PDFRendererConfigurator` that will return desired font list when `getCustomFontCollection()` is executed.

In order to do it we need to create custom `PDFDocumentHandlerMaker` that will return custom `PDFDocumentHandler` (form method `makeIFDocumentHandler()`) which will in turn return our custom `PDFRendererConfigurator` (from `getConfigurator()` method) that, as above, will set out custom font list.

Then just add custom `PDFDocumentHandlerMaker` to `RendererFactory` and it will work.

`FopFactory > RendererFactory > PDFDocumentHandlerMaker > PDFDocumentHandler > PDFRendererConfigurator`

## Full code

FopTest.java

```
public class FopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // the XSL FO file
        StreamSource xsltFile = new StreamSource(
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.xsl"));
        // the XML file which provides the input
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("employees.xml"));
        // create an instance of fop factory
        FopFactory fopFactory = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI()).build();

        RendererFactory rendererFactory = fopFactory.getRendererFactory();
        rendererFactory.addDocumentHandlerMaker(new CustomPDFDocumentHandlerMaker());

        // a user agent is needed for transformation
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

        // Setup output
        OutputStream out;
        out = new java.io.FileOutputStream("employee.pdf");

        try {
            // Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

            // Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsltFile);

            // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to
            // FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            // That's where the XML is first transformed to XSL-FO and then
            // PDF is created
            transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }

    }

}
```

CustomPDFDocumentHandlerMaker.java

```
public class CustomPDFDocumentHandlerMaker extends PDFDocumentHandlerMaker {

    @Override
    public IFDocumentHandler makeIFDocumentHandler(IFContext ifContext) {
        CustomPDFDocumentHandler handler = new CustomPDFDocumentHandler(ifContext);
        FOUserAgent ua = ifContext.getUserAgent();
        if (ua.isAccessibilityEnabled()) {
            ua.setStructureTreeEventHandler(handler.getStructureTreeEventHandler());
        }
        return handler;
    }

}
```

CustomPDFDocumentHandler.java

```
public class CustomPDFDocumentHandler extends PDFDocumentHandler {

    public CustomPDFDocumentHandler(IFContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IFDocumentHandlerConfigurator getConfigurator() {
        return new CustomPDFRendererConfigurator(getUserAgent(), new PDFRendererConfigParser());
    }

}
```

CustomPDFRendererConfigurator.java

```
public class CustomPDFRendererConfigurator extends PDFRendererConfigurator {

    public CustomPDFRendererConfigurator(FOUserAgent userAgent, RendererConfigParser rendererConfigParser) {
        super(userAgent, rendererConfigParser);
    }

    @Override
    protected FontCollection getCustomFontCollection(InternalResourceResolver resolver, String mimeType)
            throws FOPException {

        List<EmbedFontInfo> fontList = new ArrayList<EmbedFontInfo>();
        try {
            FontUris fontUris = new FontUris(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("UbuntuMono-Bold.ttf").toURI(), null);
            List<FontTriplet> triplets = new ArrayList<FontTriplet>();
            triplets.add(new FontTriplet("UbuntuMono", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_NORMAL));
            EmbedFontInfo fontInfo = new EmbedFontInfo(fontUris, false, false, triplets, null, EncodingMode.AUTO, EmbeddingMode.AUTO);
            fontList.add(fontInfo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return createCollectionFromFontList(resolver, fontList);
    }

}
```

Comment: The most inportant is not to forget to add a new font familty in `<fo:root tag`. `font-family="UbuntuMono"` in the given case. And it will work perfectly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution. What is the content of "template.xsl" ?

Comment: Is there any way to use this with PDFTranscoder?

Comment: Finally a working solution. Maybe a bit complicated, but it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. You need to set FOP's first base directory programmatically.

```
    fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
    // for image base URL : images from Resource path of project
    String serverPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    fopFactory.setBaseURL(serverPath);
    // for fonts base URL :  .ttf from Resource path of project
    fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontBaseURL(serverPath);
```

Then use FOB font config file.It will use above base path.

Just put your font files in web applications resource folder and refer that path in FOP's font config file.

**After Comment : Reading font config programmatically (not preferred & clean way still as requested)**

```
    //This is NON tested and PSEUDO code to get understanding of logic
    FontUris fontUris = new FontUris(new URI("<font.ttf relative path>"), null);
    EmbedFontInfo fontInfo = new EmbedFontInfo(fontUris, "is kerning enabled boolean", "is aldvaned enabled boolean", null, "subFontName");
    List<EmbedFontInfo> fontInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    fontInfoList.add(fontInfo);
    //set base URL for Font Manager to use relative path of ttf file.
    fopFactory.getFontManager().updateReferencedFonts(fontInfoList);
```

You can get more info for FOP's relative path https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/configuration.html

Comment: Well, is there any way NOT to use config file and do it fully programmatically?

Comment: You need to add font.ttf file in resource. To skip <font> xml , use need to overide fop's FontManager factory

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Pseudo logic added above to get understanding of what to do

Answer (score 0):

The following approach may be useful for those who use `PDFTranscoder`.

Put the following `xml` template in the resources:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fop version="1.0">
   <fonts>
       <font kerning="no" embed-url="IBM_PLEX_MONO_PATH" embedding-mode="subset">
               <font-triplet name="IBM Plex Mono" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
      </font>
   </fonts>
</fop>
```

Then one can load this xml and replace the line with font (`IBM_PLEX_MONO_PATH`) with the actual URI of the font from the resource bundle at runtime:

```kotlin
private val fopConfig = DefaultConfigurationBuilder()
    .buildFromFile(javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/fopconf.xml")?.use {
        val xml = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(it)).use { bf ->
            bf.readLines()
                .joinToString("")
                .replace(
                    "IBM_PLEX_MONO_PATH",
                    javaClass.getResource("/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono/IBMPlexMono-Text.ttf")!!.toURI().toString()
                )
        }
        val file = Files.createTempFile("fopconf", "xml")
        file.writeText(xml)
        file.toFile()
    })
```

Now one can use this config with `PDFTranscoder` and your custom fonts will be probably rendered and embedded in PDF:

```
 val pdfTranscoder = if (type == PDF) PDFTranscoder() else EPSTranscoder()
    ContainerUtil.configure(pdfTranscoder, fopConfig)
    val input = TranscoderInput(ByteArrayInputStream(svg.toByteArray()))
    ByteArrayOutputStream().use { byteArrayOutputStream ->
        val output = TranscoderOutput(byteArrayOutputStream)
        pdfTranscoder.transcode(input, output)
        byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

通过查看源代码，可以试用如下方法。

```java
InternalResourceResolver resourceResolver = fopFactory.getFontManager().getResourceResolver();
fopFactory.getFontManager().setFontSubstitutions(new FontSubstitutions() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void adjustFontInfo(FontInfo fontInfo) {
        super.adjustFontInfo(fontInfo);

        int num = fontInfo.getFonts().size() + 1;
        String internalName = null;
        for (EmbedFontInfo embedFontInfo : customFont()) {
            internalName = "F" + num;
            num++;

            LazyFont font = new LazyFont(embedFontInfo, resourceResolver, false);
            fontInfo.addMetrics(internalName, font);

            List<FontTriplet> triplets = embedFontInfo.getFontTriplets();
            for (FontTriplet triplet : triplets) {
                fontInfo.addFontProperties(internalName, triplet);
            }
        }
    }
});

private List<EmbedFontInfo> customFont() {
    List<EmbedFontInfo> fontList = new ArrayList<EmbedFontInfo>();
    
    URI fontUri1 = Paths.get("fonts/msyh.ttc").toUri();
    FontUris fontUris1 = new FontUris(fontUri1, null);
    List<FontTriplet> triplets1 = new ArrayList<FontTriplet>();
    triplets1.add(new FontTriplet("Microsoft YaHei UI", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_NORMAL));
    triplets1.add(new FontTriplet("Microsoft YaHei UI", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLD));
    EmbedFontInfo fontInfo1 = new EmbedFontInfo(fontUris1, false, false, triplets1, "Microsoft YaHei UI");
    fontList.add(fontInfo1);

    URI fontUri2 = Paths.get("fonts/msyhbd.ttc").toUri();
    FontUris fontUris2 = new FontUris(fontUri2, null);
    List<FontTriplet> triplets2 = new ArrayList<FontTriplet>();
    triplets2.add(new FontTriplet("Microsoft YaHei UI Bold", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_NORMAL));
    triplets2.add(new FontTriplet("Microsoft YaHei UI Bold", Font.STYLE_NORMAL, Font.WEIGHT_BOLD));
    EmbedFontInfo fontInfo2 = new EmbedFontInfo(fontUris2, false, false, triplets2, "Microsoft YaHei UI Bold");
    fontList.add(fontInfo2);
    
    return fontList;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).